# Pasar datos de cs a cshtml MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Manejo un proyecto el cual debe generar el cuerpo de un mensaje de correo electronico (HTML) personalizado para esto tengo un archivo .cshtml auxiliar el cual se toma como cuerpo del mensaje.
Para llenar este cuerpo en el controlador tengo una clase que obtiene el objeto seleccionado.

```
static CURSO cursoSelected = new CURSO();
public static CURSO cursoSel()
{
    return cursoSelected;
}
```

Pero no tengo claro como llamarlo y usarlo en el cshtml. Tengo esta idea pero no funciona

```
@model Proyecto.Models.Historial.cursoSel()
```

y en la seccion

```
<body>
    <label style="font-size:18px">Curso de</label>@Proyecto.Models.Historial.cursoSel().NOMBRE_CURSO< br />
</body>
```

Comment: Saludos bro! si andas iniciando con ASP.net MVC te sugiero que le des play a un workshop que hice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY ve por comida y unos refrescos, son 4 horas 4 minutos 4 segundos maratónicos iniciando en nivel básico y tratanto de cubrir la mayor cantidad de detalles cuando uno comienza en este framework.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro de entre cuales elementos quieres comunicar datos. Pero siguiendo las pautas del patrón MVC, necesitas que un controlador evoque la vista donde mostrarás los datos que necesitas, envíando a éstos como parámetro.

Por ejemplo, si tuvieras un controlador con un método GET como:

```
    public ActionResult cursoSel()
    {
        //Aquí la lógica para seleccionar el objeto que requieres enviar a la vista.

        return View(cursoSelected);//cursoSelected del tipo CURSO
    }
```

Luego, la vista que recibe el objeto seleccionado sería: `cursoSel.cshtml`. En ella deberías definir el modelo que utiliza:
`@model Proyecto.Models.CURSO`

De modo que en su cuerpo pudieras recuperar información del objeto de alguna forma como: `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nombre_Curso);`

También hay otras formas de pasar objetos a una vista, o a la vista maestra. Por mencionar, utilizando ViewBag, ViewData, TempData o variables del tipo Session (seguro que muchas formas más que ignoro).

**Controller.View Method**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx

Espero que te sirva de algo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si es esto lo que necesitas hacer, pero podrías probar lo siguiente:

En el controlador tener definido un ActionResult que devuelva el cuerpo del mensaje:

```
public ActionResult cursoSel()
{
    //Aquí la lógica para seleccionar el objeto que requieres enviar a la vista.

    return View(cursoSelected);//cursoSelected del tipo CURSO
}
```

Luego, en la vista, para obtener los datos necesarios, haces un PostBack al controlador, a la función específica:

```
<body>
<label style="font-size:18px">Curso de</label>@Url.Action("cursoSel")< br />
```

Donde "cursoSel" es el nombre de la acción dentro de tu controlador.